# Database Structure: Best Way To Set up Table for a Calendar Work Roster/Schedule (mySQL)?

Tags: mysql, calendar

I can't find a question like this after searching so I am posting.

1. making a work schedule for 10 of my colleagues for fun
2. it is calendar based (we have shifts 7 days a week, different shifts have different responsibilities - (Monday 8am-5pm Task 1, Monday 8am-5pm Task 2, Saturday 5pm-8am (night) Task 2, etc)
3. using mySQL

I can't wrap my head around the best way to set up the mySQL tables.  Anyone have any experience with this?

Say this coming Monday:

```
Monday days - Joe - Task 1
Monday days - Sally - task 2
Monday days - Mike - task 3
Monday nights - Bob - task 1,2,3
Tuesday days - Joe - Task 1
..etc..
```

Obviously this table set up is inefficient:

```
id,  date, worker, shift, task
```

it is inefficient because the 'date' field will have numerous entries in it for each day of the year... is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very interesting question, and a notoriously hard problem. Read Scott Rosenberg's *Dreaming in Code* for an account of some struggles with this and similar problems.

You have a basic design choice.  You can either enumerate the days and shifts, or you can use a wild-card-like scheme for describing time intervals.  (E.g. "all weekdays in 2013" or "Fridays and Saturdays in September 2012" or what have you.)

Enumerating the days and shifts, as you have observed, generates a lot of records. But it's easy to program. And, MySQL can handle tens of thousands of records easily.

On the other hand, a wild-card-like scheme is more elegant. But it is semantically far more complex.  The Unix / BSD / Linux crontab system (http://crontab.org/) contains a simple but ugly way of specifying this sort of thing.

For a wonderful IMPLEMENTATION of this sort of thing, check out the repeating-appointments feature set of Google Calendar.